# angular 4 app doesn't fill screen height

Tags: html, css, angular, footer

My `app.component` is like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <app-header></app-header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <footer>
    <section class="page group">
      {{ 'COMPANY.address' | translate }}
    </section>
  </footer>
</div>
```

But my footer is not at the bottom of the page.

The `wrapper` class has `min-height:100%`.

Best thing I've managed to do so far is to add inline styles to the `body` tag of `index.html` with `height:100vh` which sets the footer at the bottom, but then when content is stretching the height of the app [for example with a dropdown with many options] the footer breaks the content in half and still doesn't stick in the bottom of the page.

Something else to add, our styles are added via a `main.css` stylesheet for the whole app, so there are no other styles files separately for the components.

Angular must be adding something that I don't control. Same html page delivered by our graphic designer opens with the exact same css styles in same browser and footer works.

EDIT: Still investigating into this issue. It seems like the component that extends our page further below than where the footer is initially, stays somehow in the background, so the footer is not getting 'pushed' below that. We cannot predict how long that component will be because it's populated with data fetched from the BE.

Comment: Did you inspect the page rendered in the browser with the F12 tools? It allows you to see the styles applied to each element and to play with them. You could experiment and find the style attributes that give you the correct layout.

Comment: Yes I did, they are *exactly* the same with the sample html page and the app view! We will try work on it more, until then we'll stick to the `height:100vh` solution, since it's the overlay of some dropdowns that gets messy together with the footer. The content itself is ok. Not the best solution but ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the components that were remaining under the footer had a `float` property in their css classes.
We fixed the issue by adding a `group` class to the wrapper of those components:

```
body .group:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}
```